# Hitting url's stored in a variable in python

Tags: python, csv, curl, urllib2

The below code grabs a column from a csv file I am passing it then appends the contents of that column to a url. I tried to print those url's as a test and it works just fine. I stored those url's in a variable and now I want to hit those URLs, responses are not important to me. I tried using urllib2 but that needs to be passed a url, not a variable. How do I hit the url's I have stored in SID variable?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import sys


csvfile = list(csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1])))
for row in csvfile:
  sid = "http://myurlhere.com?sid="+row[13]
  print "%s" %sid
```

Comment: Saying that urllib2 "needs to be passed a url, not a variable" makes absolutely no sense at all. In every single sense, passing urllib2 a variable containing a URL is exactly the same as passing a literal URL string. If it's not working for you, you should show the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you pass the paramater as a variable or a hardcoded string.

```
import csv
import sys
import urllib2

csvfile = list(csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1])))
for row in csvfile:
  sid = "http://myurl.com?sid="+row[13]
  urllib2.urlopen(sid)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using urlopen(sid). You really should pay more attention to python's docs. Quoted from there:

> The simplest way to use this module is to call the urlopen function,
>   which accepts a **string** containing a URL or a Request object (described
>   below).  It opens the URL and returns the results as file-like
>   object.

As your sid variable is decidedly a string, I don't really see what the problem is...

EDIT: Hmm... I haven't logged in to StackOverflow for some times, but I thought it used to have some sort of notification if a new post was posted while we're typing. Or is my memory failing me?